# r - How to run multiple vectors through a single for loop?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a vector of vectors unsuccessfully through a     for loop.

```
data1 <- (as.list(c(1, 2, 3)))
data2 <- (as.list(c(4, 5, 6)))
data3 <- (as.list(c(7, 8, 9)))
c(data1, data2, data3) ->LoopVect
for(x in LoopVect){
unlist(x, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)-> x }
```

Whenever I run this code or similar, it treats x = "data1", "data2", "data3".
Instead I would like it to treat X's input as x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and then run the unlist function and replace the original "1" with unlist("1").

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant `list(1, 2, 3)` as the `as.list`  takes the first argument as `x` which can be a vector, so, `as.list(1, 2, 3)` basically returns a list of length 1 with 1 as value

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant as.list(c(1, 2, 3)). This seems arbitrary but it is just for the example data.